# netbeans not throwing an error if an interface is implemented but the methods are not declared

Tags: java

I'm trying to test interfaces from Design Patterns Head First. When I run my code from netbeans, I'm not getting an error, even though fly() is not declared in MallardDuck. Also is there a way to generate the methods automatically when I implement it?

```
public interface Flyable {
    public void fly();
}

public class MallardDuck extends Duck implements Flyable {

    public MallardDuck(){
       // super();

    }
}

public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        MallardDuck d = new MallardDuck();
        d.quack();
        d.fly();
    }

}
```

Comment: fly is probably implemented in Duck...

Comment: Very late, but still useful information: if write that a class implements an interfaces, netbeans will offer you the possibility to implement all interface methods by means of a clickable error in the line-number margin. If you click it, all methods will be implemented with an empty body - for you to write the actual code.